# Random password generator-concat array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble getting the users selected character sets to concat into an array.  What gets console.logged is the first array, then the first array + the second array, then 1&2nd + 3rd etc... Later on when I call the function I have it so that if nothing is selected it alerts and returns null and that part works at least, but I'm not sure how to fix retrieving the checked charsets.

```
    var charset = {
   lowerCase: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
   },
   upperCase: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
   },
   numbers: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
   },
   specialChar: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "[", "\"", "]","^", "_", "`", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\\"]
   }
}

// password length set
function lengthInput(num) {
   if (num >= 8 && num <= 128) {
      console.log(num)
      return num
   }
   else {
   alert("Please enter a number between 8 and 128")
   return null
   }
}

//create array of all enabled charsets
function getChars () {
   var result = [];
   for (key in charset) {
      if (numbers.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
      if (upperCase.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
      if (lowerCase.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
      if (specialChar.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
   }
   return result
};
```

UPDATE:So now I can create and array based on selected character sets but the array repeats itself and the returned array is at least 104 characters long.  If you continue to click generate, the array length increases exponentially

```
function getChars () {
   console.log(numbers.checked);
   for (key in charset) {
      if (numbers.checked == true) {
         result = result.concat(charset.numbers.charset);

      }
      if (upperCase.checked == true) {
         result = result.concat(charset.upperCase.charset);
         // console.log(result);
      }
      if (lowerCase.checked == true) {
         result = result.concat(charset.lowerCase.charset);
         // console.log(result);
      }
      if (specialChar.checked == true) {
         result = result.concat(charset.specialChar.charset);
         // console.log(result);
      }

   }
   console.log(result);
   return result
};
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? If its you trying to check password strength it is easy to achieve via regular expressions

Comment: are you trying to check the password strength ? @katie

Comment: @NithinChandran no I'm just trying to create and array of selected character sets

Comment: So now I can create and array based on selected character sets but the array repeats itself and the returned array is at least 104 characters long.  If you continue to click generate, the array length increases exponentially

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is due to the concat method. As per the definition taken from: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_concat_array.asp)

### Definition and Usage

The `concat()` method is used to join two or more arrays.

This method does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays.

Now, what you have to do is to reasign the concatenated arrays back to result.

```
//create array of all enabled charsets
function getChars () {
   var result = [];
   Object.keys(charsets).forEach(function(charsetType) {
     let charset = charsets[charsetType];
     if(charset.checked) {
       result = result.concat(charset.charset);
     }
   });
   return result
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
//create array of all enabled charsets
function getChars () {
   var result = [];
   for (key in charset) {
      if (numbers.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
      if (upperCase.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
      if (lowerCase.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
      if (specialChar.checked == true) {
         result += result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
   }
   return result
};
```

should change to

```
//create array of all enabled charsets
function getChars () {
   var result = [];
   for (key in charset) {
      if (charset[key].checked == true) {
         result = result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
   }
   return result
};
```

below are my total test codes:

```js
var charset = {
   lowerCase: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
   },
   upperCase: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
   },
   numbers: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
   },
   specialChar: {
      checked: false,
      charset: ["!", "#", "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "[", "\"", "]","^", "_", "`", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\\"]
   }
}

// password length set
function lengthInput(num) {
   if (num >= 8 && num <= 128) {
      console.log(num)
      return num
   }
   else {
   alert("Please enter a number between 8 and 128")
   return null
   }
}

//create array of all enabled charsets
function getChars () {
   var result = [];
   for (key in charset) {
      if (charset[key].checked == true) {
         result = result.concat(charset[key].charset);
         console.log(result);
      }
   }
   return result
};

charset['lowerCase'].checked=true
charset['numbers'].checked=true
getChars()
```

and the result:

```
(nodejs) C:\Users\s41167\Documents\nodejs>node array.js
[ 'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f',
  'g',
  'h',
  'i',
  'j',
  'k',
  'l',
  'm',
  'n',
  'o',
  'p',
  'q',
  'r',
  's',
  't',
  'u',
  'v',
  'w',
  'x',
  'y',
  'z' ]
[ 'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f',
  'g',
  'h',
  'i',
  'j',
  'k',
  'l',
  'm',
  'n',
  'o',
  'p',
  'q',
  'r',
  's',
  't',
  'u',
  'v',
  'w',
  'x',
  'y',
  'z',
  '0',
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9' ]

(nodejs) C:\Users\s41167\Documents\nodejs>
```